# jquery array into eq function

Tags: jquery, arrays

I want to send array into `eq` function as parameter. Like that:

```
$(this).find('tr').not(':eq(array)').each(function(){

});
```

I did this with using a loop and `eval` function but it doesn't look easy editable. This is my code.

```
$.fn.grilestir = function(options){

var nots = '';

for(var i=0;i<options.row_numbers.length;i++){
    nots += "not(':eq("+options.row_numbers[i]+")').";
}

    eval("$(this).find('tr')."+nots+"each(function(){\
        var tr = $(this); var orj;\
        if(options.mod == 'passive-rows'){\
            $(this).mouseover(function(){\
                orj = tr.css('backgroundColor');\
                tr.css('backgroundColor', '#777777');\
            });\
            $(this).mouseout(function(){\
                tr.css('backgroundColor', orj); \
            });\
        }\
    });");

}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If it's an array of jQuery objects, you can just do `.not(array)`. What data does your array contain? As an aside, it's never a good idea to use `eval()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming that your array contains a set of numbers that represent element indexes. The `eq` selector will not work with that.

You could use `filter` to reduce the matched set of elements to those at indexes within your array:

```
var arr = [1, 2];
$("someSelector").filter(function(index) {
    return arr.indexOf(index) > -1;
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/5mRnX/2/).

Note the use of `Array.prototype.indexOf`, which is not available in older browsers (notable IE < version 9). However, there are plenty of shims available to solve that problem. *Or*, as noted in the comments (thanks @mcgrailm), you could use [`jQuery.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/):

```
var arr = [1, 2];
$("someSelector").filter(function(index) {
    return $.inArray(index, arr) > -1;
});
```

Comment: +1 very nice I knew there was a nice neat way to do it just couldn't think of it

Comment: could jQuery's inArray() function work to cover older versions ?

Comment: @mcgrailm - Indeed it could. I always forget about that useful little thing!

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I tried this. But it doesnt work. What is wrong in my code? https://gist.github.com/cab42707cfceec706f29

Comment: @FURKANILGIN - At first glance I can't see any problems. As long as `this` is an element which has some `tr` descendants, and the indexes you specified in the array do actually exist, it should select the right rows. What happens? Check the console for any errors.

Comment: i dont have any console error. When i try to alert($(this).index()) in filter function it always gives me -1.

Comment: But im sure i select elements correctly. When i try to $(this).attr('class') it returns me right respond.

Comment: @FURKANILGIN - Try to make an example on http://jsfiddle.net. It will be easier to help you that way.

Comment: I suppose i have another mistake in my codes. Because when i try it in jsfiddle it works well.

Comment: I found the solution. I was using jquery 1.3.1 after i updated it to 1.7.1 it is fixed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @FURKANILGIN - No problem, glad you got it working :) 1.3.1 is a very old version, you are much better off using 1.7 or above!